# cin using char type array

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to read characters from `std::cin` using a `char[]` array.

Here is the simple program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {    
    int age, years;
    char name[20];

    cout << "Enter your age in years: " << endl;

    cin >> years;
    cout << "Enter your name in years: " << name[15] << endl;
    age = years * 12;

    cout << " Your age in months is: " << age << endl;

    cout << "Your name is: " << name[15] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And here what i get as an output

```
Enter your age in years:
19
Enter your name in years:
 Your age in months is: 228
Your name is:
```

It doesn't recognizing the array from `std::cin`.

Anyone can help?

Comment: You never use `name` with `cin`, only with `cout`. Also, `name[15]` is a single character from `name`. To display the whole name use `cout << name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int age  , years ;

    char name[20];

    cout <<"Enter your age in years: "<< endl;
    cin >> years;

    cout <<"Enter your name in years: " <<endl;
    cin >> name;
    age = years*12;
    cout << " Your age in months is: " << age <<endl;
    cout << "Your name is: "<< name <<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

There are two differences with your code:

```
cin << name;
(...)
cout << name << endl;
```

I'm assuming you thought

> cout << "Enter your name" << name[15] << endl;

would make it ask for input. This is not what `cout` does. `Cout` prints out stuff on the console, it doesn't ask for input. That's `cin`'s task.

Also you don't put [15] after the array name, this would just print out the 15th character in your array, which would be a garbage character as long as the name entered does not reach a length of 15.

Answer (score 0):

```
int age, years;
char name[20];
cout << "Enter your age in years: " << endl;
cin >> years;
cout << "Enter your name in years: " << endl;
age = years * 12;
cin >> name;
cout << " Your age in months is: " << age << endl;
cout << "Your name is: " << name << endl;
cin.get();
```

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers)